# maven ignoring findbugs suppressFBWarnings annotation

Tags: maven, maven-plugin, findbugs

I have 2 projects that I am using the `FindBugs` plugin in `maven` to identify bugs. I am also using the `@SuppressFBWarnings` annotation to ignore specific bugs.

With the first project, I added the dependancies to the pom.xml and both the findbugs report and the annotation worked fine. With the second project, the report gets generated, but it still identifies bugs that I have suppressed using the annotation.

I run `mvn clean install site` to generate the reports on my machine in the build folder.

Each of the 2 projects I mentioned, have sub-projects with their own pom.xml files in their sub-directories, so in the parent directory, I also have a pom.xml. This directory layout is mirrored identically in both of the main projects.

Here is the XML I added to the parent poms under the `<reporting>` tag:

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
    <artifactId>findbugs-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>2.3.2</version>
    <configuration>
        <xmlOutput>true</xmlOutput>
        <findbugsXmlOutput>true</findbugsXmlOutput>
        <fork>true</fork>
        <threshold>Low</threshold>
        <effort>Min</effort>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```

Also, in this same parent pom, I added this to the `<dependencyManagement><dependencies>` section:

```
<dependency>
        <groupId>com.google.code.findbugs</groupId>
        <artifactId>annotations</artifactId>
        <version>2.0.1</version>
</dependency>
```

This is identical in both of the main projects poms.

Now, in the sub-projects where I actually use the `@SuppressFBWarnings` annotation, and only in that particular sub-project, I have this under `<dependencies>`:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.google.code.findbugs</groupId>
    <artifactId>annotations</artifactId>
    <version>2.0.1</version>
</dependency>
```

Also, this is mirrored in the other working project. I copied and pasted directly.

One project works perfect and I can successfully suppress false positives. The other project completely ignores the `@SuppressFBWarnings` anotation, and I can't seem to fix it.

Is there something I'm missing here?

I think that if an annotation is not found, instead of giving an error, it will just ignore it? How can I tell if its not found?

Hopefully this is a simple fix.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to add annotations artifcat to the plugin dependencies :

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
    <artifactId>findbugs-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>2.3.2</version>
    <configuration>
        <xmlOutput>true</xmlOutput>
        <findbugsXmlOutput>true</findbugsXmlOutput>
        <fork>true</fork>
        <threshold>Low</threshold>
        <effort>Min</effort>
    </configuration>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.code.findbugs</groupId>
            <artifactId>annotations</artifactId>
            <version>2.0.1</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</plugin>
```

Comment: Hi Omar, thanks for the reply, but when I try that, I get this error: `cvc-complex-type.2.4.a: Invalid content was found starting with element 'dependencies'. One of '{"http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0":inherited, "http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0":reportSets}' is expected.`

Comment: May be there is an invisible character in thé file. Try to show hidden characters with your text editor (notpad++, for instence)

Comment: I forgot to follow up. Basically, I got it working by using the normal findbugs `SuppressWarnings` instead of `SuppressFBWarnings`. I think there was an issue with the standard `SuppressWarnings` annotation and the findbugs one, possibly combined with a JAR issue.

Comment: eoinzy: means you didn't get it working with SuppressFBWarnings at all? It didn't work for me when I tried it as described here.

Answer (score 2):

@SuppressFBWarnings was introduced with the annotation in version 3. That's why it should look like this:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.google.code.findbugs</groupId>
    <artifactId>annotations</artifactId>
    <version>3.0.1</version>
</dependency>
```

Answer (score 0):

Ensure that the dependency added is in between the dependencies tags. 
Like this:

```
<dependencies>
  <dependency>
     <groupId>something</groupId>
     <artifactId>something</artifactId>
      <version>something</version>
  </dependency>
<dependencies>
```